# insertion in a table of objects with nested table in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a problem inserting in a nested table in oracle

These are the relevant types and tables;

```
create type movies_type as Table of ref movie_type;

create type actor_type under person_type

(

starring movies_type

) Final;

create table actor of actor_type

NESTED TABLE starring STORE AS starring_nt;
```

this is how i tried to insert

```
insert into actor values
(actor_type(29,'Carrie','Fisher',TO_DATE('21/10/1956', 'DD/MM/YY'),TO_DATE('27/12/2016', 'DD/MM/YY'),'USA', movies_type(select ref(m) from movie m where movie_id in (7, 8, 9))));
```

this doesn't work, it gives

```
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

which isn't very helpful.

i also tried nesting the select statement in parenthesis because i thought it might have been a syntax error

```
insert into actor values
(actor_type(29,'Carrie','Fisher',TO_DATE('21/10/1956', 'DD/MM/YY'),TO_DATE('27/12/2016', 'DD/MM/YY'),'USA', movies_type((select ref(m) from movie m where movie_id in (7, 8, 9)))));
```

but it said

```
SQL ERROR ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

so i changed it to this

```
insert into actor values
(actor_type(29,'Carrie','Fisher',TO_DATE('21/10/1956', 'DD/MM/YY'),TO_DATE('27/12/2016', 'DD/MM/YY'),'USA', movies_type((select ref(m) from movie m where movie_id=7))));
```

which worked but it isn't what i want since it doesn't allow me to have multiple values in

```
movies_type
```

i don't understand what the problem is exactly and the errors messages aren't helpful

**why does it say missing expression?**

**and why in the second case it gives single-row subquery returns more than one row?**

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `CAST` and `COLLECT` to aggregate the references into a collection:

```sql
insert into actor values(
  actor_type(
    29,
    'Carrie',
    'Fisher',
    DATE '1956-10-21',
    DATE '2016-12-27',
    'USA',
    (
      SELECT CAST( COLLECT(REF(m)) AS movies_type )
      FROM   movie m
      WHERE  movie_id IN (7, 8, 9)
    )
  )
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=996480accf8b979caccad5a10dad1560)*

---

> ```
> insert into actor values (actor_type(29,'Carrie','Fisher',TO_DATE('21/10/1956', 'DD/MM/YY'),TO_DATE('27/12/2016', 'DD/MM/YY'),'USA', movies_type(select ref(m) from movie m where movie_id in (7, 8, 9))));
> ```
>
> why does it say missing expression?

Because you have `movie_type()` where the `()` brackets are for the object's constructor and then inside you have a `SELECT` statement that is nested inside another statement that is not surrounded in `()` brackets (as the surrounding brackets are for the constructor).

> so i changed it to this
>
> ```
> insert into actor values (actor_type(29,'Carrie','Fisher',TO_DATE('21/10/1956', 'DD/MM/YY'),TO_DATE('27/12/2016', 'DD/MM/YY'),'USA', movies_type((select ref(m) from movie m where movie_id=7))));
> ```
>
> and why in the second case it gives single-row subquery returns more than one row?

Because, when you use `WHERE movie_id IN (7,8,9)` the query is returning 3 rows and it needs to return only a single row; for that you need to aggregate the multiple rows into a single row containing a collection.

> what's wrong with multiple rows as parameters to the constructor?

The constructor expects a single item in each argument so you would need to use:

```
insert into actor values (
  actor_type(
    29,
    'Carrie',
    'Fisher',
    DATE '1956-10-21',
    DATE '2016-12-27',
    'USA',
    movies_type(
      (select ref(m) from movie m where movie_id=7),
      (select ref(m) from movie m where movie_id=8),
      (select ref(m) from movie m where movie_id=9)
    )
  )
);
```

This would work (assuming `movie_id` is unique; if it isn't and things like the theatrical version and the director's cut of the same movie have the same `movie_id` then it still would raise exceptions) but it may use a table/index scans for each `SELECT` and would be less efficient than collating all the rows in a single `SELECT` using `CAST`/`COLLECT`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and informative answer,
i don't get your explanation of why it said `missing statement`
as i understand, if i were to replace the select with actual refs it would work fine, so why doesn't it work when trying to initialize it with a select statement.

Comment: you said  that "SELECT statement that is nested inside another statement that is not surrounded in () brackets", why does it have to be surrounded by brackets?

Comment: also, i get that the multi row error was because of multiple rows returned from the select statement, but why is that a problem? what's wrong with multiple rows as parameters to the constructor?

Comment: @user062 Regarding your comment "why does it have to be surrounded by brackets?" the answer is that is how the SQL syntax is defined and not doing it is a syntax error and Oracle communicates that by saying `missing expression` (i.e. you wrote something but the SQL engine cannot parse it as any of the options by its allowed SQL syntax so a valid expression is missing).

Comment: As for your other comments, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very very much, that clarifies a lot.
One last thing, do you have suggestions on how to learn sql and relational databases properly? i mean not just, to accomplish X type Y, but with rationale on why things are the way they are, i just want to build a clear precise mental model for it.

Comment: @user062 Sorry, no. Some information you can find in the documentation (Oracle's documentation is detailed but not always easy to read), other bits like why you need to use valid syntax is from learning about compiler engineering and others is just a gradual accumulation as you learn over years.